# phpmyadmin says restricted access

Tags: phpmyadmin, softaculous

I installed phpmyadmin with Softaculous on my webspace in a folder named data. When I go to the phpmyadmin link it provided after install it says like restricted access!. I made sure all access was marked 777. Any help with this would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Can you check your webserver error log for any hints?